# В некоторых окнах не работает ввод текста с помощью python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, клавиатура, pywinauto

Мне нужно ввести переменную в окно windows когда я попробовал ввести текст в notepad либо же cmd то все работало но когда я решил ввести текст в окно Steam то у меня ничего не получилось, хотя если просто набрать текст на клавиатуре то все отлично вводется
Использовал модули keyboard,pyautogui,pywinauto
ни с каким из выше приведенных модулей ввод текста не работал
как решить эту проблему

`code = 'some_text`

keyboard -  `keyboard.write(code, delay=0.05)`

pywinauto - `send_keys(code)`

pyautogui - `pyautogui.write(code)`

Comment: Помогло в итоге?

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Да Спасибо

Comment: Тогда, наверно, стоит заакцептить ответ. Просто чтоб другие люди не тратили время на чтение хотя бы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё дело в фокусе ввода. Но можно и без него. Вот накидал за 20 минут для интерфейса на английском:

```
from pywinauto.application import Application

app = Application(backend="uia").start(cmd_line=ur'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" ')
steam = app.window(title='Steam')
steam.wait('ready', timeout=20)
steam.type_keys('{ENTER}')

create_account = app.window(title='Create Your Account')
create_account.wait('ready', timeout=15)
create_account.child_window(title="Email Address", control_type="Edit").set_text("some-address@something.com")
```

Метод `.type_keys()` - он на крайний случай, и чаще всего не для edit box'ов. Он ставит фокус ввода и вызывает `pywinauto.keyboard.send_keys()`. Вот [документация](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.keyboard.html) по `keyboard.send_keys()`, всё то же самое можно через `.type_keys()` делать, только для ввода пробелов надо `with_spaces=True` передать.

P.S. Конечно, в этом примере не обрабатывается окно обновления или ошибка загрузки окна из сети (там явно веб содержимое). Но каков вопрос, таков и ответ. Дальше можно и самому поизучать. Рекомендую начать с [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html), потом [Waiting for Long Operations](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wait_long_operations.html).